# why this code doesn't produce a tab pane?

Tags: javafx, fxml

```
    <TabPane fx:controller="application.FXMLcontrolor" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

and the controller is like this

```
    public class FXMLcontrolor extends TabPane
{

    public FXMLcontrolor()
    {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource( "FXMLdocument.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try
        {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and the main is like this:

```
 public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
    {

        FXMLcontrolor mainControllor=new FXMLcontrolor();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainControllor));
        stage.setTitle("Custom Control");
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(400);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the result has no tab in it, why this doesn't show any tab? I have used FXML to creat a UI, and a controllor, what I must do? Infact, I am looking for a way to manage a tab pane with several tabs and several controls in each of them, but even in implementing this simple example I have problem.

[image]

Comment: This does not even compile for me.

Comment: You should always include the stack trace (exception) that you get in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting the root dynamically with

```
fxmlLoader.setRoot(...);
```

you need to use the `<fx:root>` element as the root element of the FXML. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components).

Additionally, if you set the controller in code with

```
fxmlLoader.setController(...);
```

you should *not* specify a `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file. So your FXML file should be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<fx:root type="TabPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="ALL_TABS" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65">
  <tabs>
    <Tab  text="Untitled Tab 1">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane  minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: this works, but I see your reference, what these sentences mean:

Comment: The setRoot() and setController() methods of FXMLLoader allow a caller to inject document root and controller values, respectively, into the document namespace, rather than delegating creation of these values to FXMLLoader itself. This allows a developer to easily create reusable controls that are internally implemented using markup, but (from an API perspective) appear identically to controls implemented programmatically.

Comment: @delsa They mean exactly what they say: not sure I can clarify much. If you call `setRoot(..)` the root element is specified by the Java code, not created by the `FXMLLoader` according to the root element of the FXML file. So it makes no sense to specify a class as the root of the FXML; you use `<fx:root>` instead. Similarly, `setController(...)` specifies a controller. If you specify a controller, one is not created by the `FXMLLoader`, so it makes no sense to instruct the `FXMLLoader` to create one, which is what the `fx:controller` attribute does.